# How to realize interface?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

Now I'm studying interfaces and can't understand some things like a interface realizing. For example I have some code:

```
IModelDoc2 swModel; //IModelDoc2 is an interface. What are we doing here? 
boolstatus = swModel.Extension.SelectByID2(.....); //Some parameters
```

I can't understand how can we implement this method by calling from interface. Class can implement interface and we can call methods from class. Right? But how can we implement methods from interface?

Comment: As the name suggests, an interface defines an interface to access methods of an object. A class implementing an interface must implement these methods and as a result, allows you to call these methods on an instance of this class.

Comment: I think probably some extended tutorials or C# books should be on your list of things to consult. What learning resources are you using now?

Comment: what is behind in closing this question. The question is related to  IT .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to implement an interface member: explicit and implicit:

explicit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

implicit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664590%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

The apparent benefit of explicit is: if the **compile-time type** (declared type) of some variable/member is the class implementing the interface, explicitly implemented members cannot be called directly, you would need an interface reference to do that. But you should not cast try to cast a class or structure variable to interface type. Instead, you should properly use patterns of the interface use. Interface is a powerful abstraction tool, it allows to abstract some code from knowing the implementation. It means that this part of code should be agnostic to implementation and never receive the class reference of structure objects implementing the interface, it should receive only the interface pointer:

```
interface MyInterface {
   void MyMethod(/*...*/);
   int MyOtherMethod(/*...*/);
   string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

class MyImplementation : MyInterface {
    // explicit implementations:
    void MyInterface.MyMethod (/*...*/) { /* ... */ }
    string MyInterface.MyProperty { get { return /*...*/; } set { something = value; /*...*/ } }
    // or even implicit:
    public int MyOtherMethod(/*...*/) { /* ... */ return /*...*/; }
    // Now, even you may have some public (better be internal) members,
    // they should not be used in implementation-agnostic code
    internal void SomeNonInterfaceMethod(/*...*/) { /*...*/ }
}

//...

MyInterface myImplementation = new MyImplementation(/*...*/);
// NOT MyInterface myImplementation = new MyImplementation(/*...*/);

//...

//some implementation-agnostic method:
void SomeUsingMethod(MyInterface implementation) { // NOT MyImplementation implementation
                                                   // it would kill the abstraction
    implementation.MyMethod(/*...*/);
    implementation.MyProperty = "some value";
    // but you cannot call
    // implementation.SomeNonInterfaceMethod(/*...*/); // won't work
    // if somewhere you need to do this
    MyImplementation violatedEncapsulationImplementation = (MyImplementation)implementation; // AVOID IT!
    violatedEncapsulationImplementation.SomeNonInterfaceMethod(/*...*/); // AVOID IT!
    // it would work, but it would be an indication of wrong code design
}
```

Now, you know the basic idea.

Comment: +1. Note that default naming convention in C# is to name interfaces with "I" - like `IMyInterface`.

Answer (score 1):

All an interface is...in its simplest form...is the implementation for a class. One of the big benefits (to me) that interfaces provide is de-coupling your code...essentially it makes your code less dependent upon other classes.

Example situation.

Say you have 3 different currencies, US Dollar, Indian Rupee, and the Euro. Without an interface you would have this code.

```
UsDollar currency1 = new UsDollar();
```

To work with the respective classes. If you wanted to swap out the UsDollar for a Rupee, you'd have to swap out the code/make any changes necessary to support the next class

```
Rupee currency1 = new Rupee();
```

But by using an interface, you can de-couple the dependency upon the specific class being used and use the interface instead (similar to how your example snippet you posted).

So Say you have an interface that implements an integer of CurrencyValue and a method of Exchange Rate

```
public interface ICurrency
{
    int CurrencyValue { get; set; }
    void ExchangeRate(double percent);
}
```

You would then have the following 3 classes that inherit from the Interface. Remember, if a class inherits from that interface, they must implement the same as what the interface implements.

```
public class UsDollar : ICurrency
{
    public int CurrencyValue { get; set; }

    public void ExchangeRate(double percent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your Exchange Rate for Us Dollar is {0}", CurrencyValue * percent);
    }
}

public class Euro : ICurrency
{
    public int CurrencyValue { get; set; }

    public void ExchangeRate(double percent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your Exchange Rate for Euro is {0}", CurrencyValue * percent);
    }
}

public class Rupee : ICurrency
{
    public int CurrencyValue { get; set; }

    public void ExchangeRate(double percent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your Exchange Rate for Rupee is {0}", CurrencyValue * percent);
    }
}
```

So the by changing your usage from

```
Rupee currency1 = new Rupee();
```

To

```
ICurrency currency1 = new Rupee();
```

Your code that is using this class no longer cares if it is a Rupee, Us Dollar, Euro...or whatever other currency classes you end up creating.

Interfaces can also provide value in various design patterns as well (factor pattern).

Example Usage:

```
ICurrency currency1 = new UsDollar();
ICurrency currency2 = new Euro();
ICurrency currency3 = new Rupee();

currency1.CurrencyValue = 10;
currency2.CurrencyValue = 13;
currency3.CurrencyValue = 16;

currency1.ExchangeRate(1.1);
currency2.ExchangeRate(1.6);
currency3.ExchangeRate(1.5);
```

So to answer your question

```
IModelDoc2 swModel; //IModelDoc2 is an interface. What are we doing here?
```

This should specifically be creating a new object of some class type (in my example this would be same as ICurrency currency1 = new UsDollar();). So somewhere in your code you would be assigning the value to swModel which would be some class/type that inherits from IModelDoc2.

Hope this helps/clarifies things for you.

But to read up on interfaces i would suggest the link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand polymorphism to understand the difference between what's seen by the  calling code and what's done by the actual implementation.

The implementation has to have an actual class (ignore edge cases) that implements that interface.

The calling may only see an interface, but the actual type of that variable has to be some class that implements that interface.

Your example:

```
IModelDoc2 swModel; //IModelDoc2 is an interface. What are we doing here? 
boolstatus = swModel.Extension.SelectByID2(.....); //Some parameters
```

will not even compile as `swModel` is not initialized.

Correct code would be

```
IModelDoc2 swModel = new SomeClassImplementingIModelDoc2();
boolstatus = swModel.Extension.SelectByID2(.....); //Some parameters
```